# Would it be possible for someone to develop a tolerance for electric shock?

Tags: survival, super-powers, electricity

I understand that it is possible to gradually develop a tolerance to a substance by consuming small amounts of it to the point of being unharmed by an amount of the substance that is deadly to most people.  Would it be possible for someone to develop a tolerance to being electrocuted by gradually subjecting him/herself to small amounts of electricity and gradually increasing the voltage of the electric shocks to him/herself?  Could a person build up enough of a tolerance to electric shock to be completely unharmed by an amount of electricity that would be more than enough to kill most people?

Comment: I had a friend who owned a trampoline and eventually wasn't at all bothered by the shocks he'd get from it, even when they made a loud crack.  But that's just pain.  There are a few specific cases that might be workable for dangerous currents.  No chance this is high-frequency AC, is it?  Radio-frequency even?  Are we concerned with specific points of contact?  Can we have visible adaptations like callouses?

Comment: It's actually current sustained over time that does the damage, rather than voltage.

Comment: It's pain tolerance, not tolerance to the damage being done.

Comment: Consuming small amounts of poisons to build up tolerance is mostly urban legend.  Many poisons are cumulative - meaning if you take very small doses over long periods of time, you will die.  The human body is used to processing a large set of different chemicals.  It basically keeps what it needs and flushes or breaks down the rest.  Poisoning happens when the body can't chemically distinguish between a desired and harmful chemical (e.g. arsenic or carbon monoxide), when the body gets too much of a desired chemical, or it's an organic chemical it can't break down (e.g. venom).

Comment: Depends on the poison. **If** it is detoxified by enzymes in your liver, then repeated small doses may boost the level of the detox enzymes so that a normally fatal dose isn't.

Answer (score 6):

The equivalent comparison is not about toxic substances, it's closer to shooting yourself with bullets of ever increasing size to build up tolerance, it's not going to work.

The human body runs on electricity and is damaged by high flows.

I'll leave you with the ever popular [health and safety executive](http://www.hse.gov.uk/electricity/injuries.htm)

> A voltage as low as 50 volts applied between two parts of the human body causes a current to flow that can block the electrical signals between the brain and the muscles. This may have a number of effects including:
>
> - Stopping the heart beating properly
> - Preventing the person from breathing
> - Causing muscle spasms
>
> The exact effect is dependent upon a large number of things including the size of the voltage, which parts of the body are involved, how damp the person is, and the length of time the current flows.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

It's possible to develop mental tolerance of painful stimuli. Many electrical shocks cause pain by direct stimulation of nerves but are otherwise harmless or cause only minor injury at the points of contact.

It's not possible to develop tolerance of one's heart ceasing to beat (fibrillation) or one's flesh and (especially) nerves being cooked. These are respectively what a smallish shock passing through your heart and a massive shock passing through any part of you will do.

And it's not possible to steel youself to perform heroic acts on an electrically live conductor using your bare hands. While current is flowing through your nerves you will have no control of your muscles. Find some insulating plastic sheet and then be a hero.

Answer (score -1):

My neighbour, who is an old school electrician, came to my house today to help me with some old "cater" 3 way switches.  I watched him use his fingers to figure out which wires were hot.

He repeatedly put his fingers (from the same hand) on positive and negative and even used the junction box as the ground at points. We are talking about 5 second stints of holding his fingers on the live wires.

I asked him about it and he said he built up a tolerance over 30 plus years but said it IS dangerous, because it can affect your heart and other organs.  At certain points he couldn't even tell what was hot, because his hands were numb.

Funny side note is he swore that he has a full head of hair from doing this and that every other male in his family is completely bald.